# Is there hard data on close votes?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, reopening-questions

I'm wondering if there's any data/statistics on the percentage of close votes that age away vs end in closure vs end with the question being reopened here on Worldbuilding. Perhaps even some breakdown of questions closed by close reason would be useful? Maybe even a breakdown by tag?

As we discuss site policies it would be nice to have hard numbers to look at on occasion.

Comment: Before someone suggests it I've played with the SE Data Explorer, but unfortunately my sql skills leave a lot to be desired...

Comment: Somebody please test this for me: can 10k users see [this page in Review/Tools](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days)?  That has some of the desired data (only for the last 90 days).

Comment: @Monica yes some of the data appears to be there, I can access it on other sites, but unfortunately I'm not as privileged here.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Shows up just fine to me, and gives per-close-reason statistics, very similar to that shown in the screenshot in your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spent a bit of time digging into this. I looked at the past 365 of questions posted on the site to get the numbers. Here is what I found:

Over the past 365 days, there were **6,534** questions asked, of these:

- 3,313 have received at least one close vote or flag,
- 2,135 questions were closed,
- 1,534 of the questions had at least one close vote or flag that aged away, and
- of the questions that were closed, 139 were reopened by the community

Breaking these numbers down by close reasons, here are the total number of *flags/votes on questions, and then total number of those votes/flags that aged away by close reason:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|                                Flag/Close Vote Reason                                 | # Flags / CVs | # Flags / CVs Aged Away |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| Too broad                                                                             |          4394 |                     881 |
| Primarily opinion-based                                                               |          2892 |                     601 |
| Off-topic This question does not appear to be about **worldbuilding**, within the sco |          2393 |                     424 |
| Unclear what you're asking                                                            |          2108 |                     389 |
| Off-topic You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about buil |          1202 |                     322 |
| Duplicate                                                                             |          1196 |                     186 |
| Off-topic Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)                              |           164 |                      48 |
| Off-topic This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network         |            62 |                       1 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

I also looked at the questions that had been closed and then received reopen votes/flags to see how many of them aged away.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
|                                     Close Reason                                      | # Reopen Votes | # Reopen Votes Aged Away |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
| Too broad                                                                             |            152 |                        4 |
| Off-topic This question does not appear to be about **worldbuilding**, within the sco |            111 |                        0 |
| Unclear what you're asking                                                            |            111 |                        3 |
| Primarily opinion-based                                                               |             98 |                        9 |
| Off-topic You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about buil |             60 |                        2 |
| Duplicate                                                                             |             52 |                        2 |
| Off-topic Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)                              |              4 |                        0 |
| Off-topic This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network         |              3 |                        0 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------+
```

Far fewer reopen votes were cast, so even less of them aged away, but over the past year, approximately 19% of close votes/flags aged away.

As requested here are the comparisons to the other sites on the network for Pct Aged Away:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|                     Site Name                     | Pct Aged Away |
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Freelancing Stack Exchange                        | 54.18         |
| Esperanto Language Stack Exchange                 | 47.58         |
| Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange            | 45.88         |
| Martial Arts                                      | 42.35         |
| Sustainable Living                                | 40            |
| Stack Overflow                                    | 37.59         |
| Homebrew                                          | 33.33         |
| Coffee Stack Exchange                             | 31.86         |
| Linguistics                                       | 30.97         |
| Super User                                        | 29.88         |
| Health Stack Exchange                             | 29.16         |
| Graphic Design                                    | 28.75         |
| 3D Printing Stack Exchange                        | 28.54         |
| Chinese Language and Usage                        | 28.16         |
| Mythology Stack Exchange                          | 26.9          |
| History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange | 26.53         |
| Audio-Video Production                            | 26.31         |
| Programmers                                       | 25.67         |
| Arduino Stack Exchange                            | 24.88         |
| Tridion Stack Exchange                            | 24.75         |
| Computer Science                                  | 24.64         |
| Software Recommendations Stack Exchange           | 24.39         |
| Amateur Radio Stack Exchange                      | 24.22         |
| Photography                                       | 24.11         |
| Open Data Stack Exchange                          | 23.95         |
| Project Management                                | 23.9          |
| Jewish Life and Learning                          | 23.78         |
| Open Source Stack Exchange                        | 23.51         |
| Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair              | 22.96         |
| Emacs Stack Exchange                              | 22.77         |
| Server Fault                                      | 22.65         |
| Game Developers                                   | 22.65         |
| German Language and Usage                         | 22.24         |
| elementary OS Stack Exchange                      | 22.07         |
| Beer Stack Exchange                               | 21.95         |
| Quantitative Finance                              | 21.69         |
| Startups Stack Exchange                           | 21.4          |
| Pets Stack Exchange                               | 21.26         |
| Law Stack Exchange                                | 21.17         |
| Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange                | 21.11         |
| Expatriates Stack Exchange                        | 20.97         |
| Literature                                        | 20.75         |
| Economics                                         | 20.69         |
| Korean Language Stack Exchange                    | 20.59         |
| Ebooks Stack Exchange                             | 20.41         |
| Cognitive Sciences                                | 19.99         |
| Worldbuilding Stack Exchange                      | 19.75         |
| Latin Language Stack Exchange                     | 19.75         |
| The Great Outdoors                                | 19.66         |
| CiviCRM Stack Exchange                            | 19.08         |
| Cooking                                           | 18.97         |
| Moderators Stack Exchange                         | 18.75         |
| Music Fans Stack Exchange                         | 18.16         |
| Philosophy                                        | 17.7          |
| WordPress                                         | 17.16         |
| Buddhism Stack Exchange                           | 17.14         |
| Chess                                             | 17.11         |
| Politics                                          | 17.11         |
| Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange                      | 17.11         |
| Lifehacks Stack Exchange                          | 17.06         |
| Writers                                           | 16.75         |
| Theoretical Computer Science                      | 16.62         |
| Raspberry Pi                                      | 16.18         |
| Retrocomputing Stack Exchange                     | 15.98         |
| Sitecore Stack Exchange                           | 15.59         |
| Internet of Things Stack Exchange                 | 15.55         |
| Computer Graphics Stack Exchange                  | 15.49         |
| Gardening and Landscaping                         | 15.31         |
| Biology                                           | 15.3          |
| Stack Overflow на русском                         | 15.2          |
| Woodworking Stack Exchange                        | 15.18         |
| ExpressionEngine                                  | 15.15         |
| Bicycles                                          | 14.91         |
| Russian Language and Usage                        | 14.86         |
| Aviation Stack Exchange                           | 14.58         |
| Astronomy                                         | 14.57         |
| Language Learning Stack Exchange                  | 14.14         |
| Sports                                            | 14.09         |
| English Language Learners                         | 13.94         |
| Apple                                             | 13.67         |
| Sound Design Stack Exchange                       | 13.63         |
| Blender Stack Exchange                            | 13.62         |
| Islam                                             | 13.59         |
| Computational Science                             | 13.28         |
| Board and Card Games                              | 13.16         |
| Earth Science Stack Exchange                      | 13.06         |
| Hinduism Stack Exchange                           | 12.86         |
| Skeptics                                          | 12.75         |
| Engineering Stack Exchange                        | 12.64         |
| Puzzling Stack Exchange                           | 12.41         |
| Movies                                            | 12.38         |
| Personal Productivity                             | 12.33         |
| Japanese Language and Usage                       | 12.1          |
| Personal Finance and Money                        | 12.09         |
| Bitcoin                                           | 12.01         |
| Windows Phone                                     | 11.83         |
| Parenting                                         | 11.68         |
| Android Enthusiasts                               | 11.63         |
| Software Quality Assurance and Testing            | 11.62         |
| Biblical Hermeneutics                             | 11.5          |
| Role-playing Games                                | 11.29         |
| French Language and Usage                         | 10.92         |
| The Workplace                                     | 10.87         |
| Vi and Vim Stack Exchange                         | 10.84         |
| MathOverflow                                      | 10.76         |
| Christianity                                      | 10.75         |
| Signal Processing                                 | 10.66         |
| Science Fiction                                   | 10.61         |
| Travel                                            | 10.61         |
| Stack Overflow em Português                       | 10.11         |
| Ethereum Stack Exchange                           | 10.1          |
| Web Apps                                          | 10.07         |
| Home Improvement                                  | 9.95          |
| Mathematics                                       | 9.56          |
| Fitness and Nutrition                             | 9.51          |
| Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange              | 9.51          |
| Space Exploration Stack Exchange                  | 8.98          |
| Statistical Analysis                              | 8.96          |
| Portuguese Language Stack Exchange                | 8.82          |
| Academia                                          | 8.76          |
| History                                           | 8.65          |
| Joomla Stack Exchange                             | 8.6           |
| Data Science Stack Exchange                       | 8.36          |
| Ubuntu                                            | 8.26          |
| Code Review                                       | 8.08          |
| Spanish Language and Usage                        | 7.92          |
| Patents                                           | 7.81          |
| English Language and Usage                        | 7.8           |
| Salesforce                                        | 7.8           |
| SharePoint                                        | 7.76          |
| Stack Overflow en español                         | 7.74          |
| Genealogy and Family History                      | 7.5           |
| Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange           | 7.46          |
| Monero Stack Exchange                             | 7.44          |
| Database Administrators                           | 7.31          |
| Magento                                           | 7.28          |
| Gaming                                            | 7.26          |
| LEGO®                                             | 7.19          |
| Italian Language Stack Exchange                   | 7.14          |
| Poker                                             | 7.01          |
| IT Security                                       | 6.91          |
| User Experience                                   | 6.86          |
| Craft CMS Stack Exchange                          | 6.69          |
| Physics                                           | 6.66          |
| Code Golf                                         | 6.6           |
| Musical Practice and Performance                  | 6.39          |
| Drupal Answers                                    | 6.3           |
| Electronics and Robotics                          | 6.27          |
| Mathematica                                       | 6.22          |
| Anime and Manga                                   | 5.89          |
| Unix and Linux                                    | 5.64          |
| Robotics                                          | 5.2           |
| Cryptography                                      | 5.06          |
| Chemistry                                         | 4.65          |
| GIS                                               | 4.62          |
| Stack Apps                                        | 4.4           |
| Webmasters                                        | 3.52          |
| TeX - LaTeX                                       | 3.32          |
| Tor Stack Exchange                                | 3.18          |
| Network Engineering Stack Exchange                | 1.44          |
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Any idea about how this compares to other sites? 25% seems like a lot.

Comment: 37% on Stack Overflow, @apaul34208. Going by questions per day though, Islam has 14% and webmasters has 4%.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm guessing that it's high on SO, because of the high traffic... Are Webmasters and Islam more comparable?

Comment: @apaul34208 I can pull some comparisons next week.

Comment: @Shog9 just glancing at the front pages it looks like Worldbuilding has slightly more traffic than Islam, and quite a bit more than Webmasters... Just trying to put the figures in perspective. Would you say that 25% is high, or reasonable?

Comment: Neither, @apaul - there's missing info here, namely: how many of these votes were aged because of review. Maybe bluefeet can add that next week.

Comment: @apaul34208 I'm still going to pull some comparisons but in doing so, I found a bug in my code for the flags/CVs that age away. I just fixed that which drops the percent of aging away to 19% instead of 25%.

Comment: No worries, thanks for taking the time to work on this for us.

Comment: @apaul34208 I've also added the site comparisons from around the network. This just includes the percent of flags/votes that have aged away.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if votes that age away are tracked anywhere.

Users with 10k rep can see some [close/reopen statistics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) for the last 90 days.  For each close reason, it includes the number closed, the number of those that were reopened, the number edited, and the number edited and reopened, like this:

[image: screenshot of close/reopen stats]

(I don't have time to figure out how to make that into a nice table.  Anybody who does, feel free to edit!)

"Too broad" is by far our biggest closure reason, at 34% of closures.  This also seems like the one where edits would help a lot, and, in fact, more than a third of them got edited.  But only a small fraction got reopened.  Is that because people aren't noticing and voting to reopen, or because the edits aren't enough?  ("Primarily opinion-based" is the next-most-common reason and has a similar pattern.)

I suggest a deeper review of "too broad".  What can we do to help those questions get fixed and reopened?

Comment: That helps, but aged away data would be really useful. I'm not sure if it's just my perception, but it looks like most questions get at least one or two close votes.

Comment: I don't know of a way to get aged-away data, unfortunately.  Just to be clear, these stats are for questions that were actually closed, not just ones that got close votes.

Comment: So only 9,5 % of all closed questions get reopened.

Comment: @Vincent not even that many, it looks like. There are two issues: (1) a bunch of questions were edited but still weren't reopened, & (2) the majority weren't edited after closure (did people give up? did they not know what to do?). We should try to understand what's going on with both & whether we need to improve any of our guidance; that said, I suggest starting w/ the cases where people tried to rescue questions with edits but that wasn't enough. What's going on there? Unfortunately we can't get convenient lists of questions in each group, so it'll take work even to get to a starting point.